# Is this formal logic explanation of the difference between "что-нибудь" and "что-то"?

Tags: терминология

In formal logic, there is the notion of a distinction between ["free variables" and "bounded variables"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables).

I found this distinction difficult to understand, until I thought of it this way: free variables are indeterminate things which can be expressed in Russian as что-нибудь, while bound variables are unspecified things which can be expressed in Russian as что-то.

> **Question:** Is this explanation correct? Do Russians (who know about formal logic) think about the concepts of свободные и связанные переменные?

The concepts really did not make much sense to me until I thought about them this way. Also this might not be a question strictly about the Russian language or culture, in which case I apologize and would gladly learn about a better place to ask. ([StackOverflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)?)

**Related questions:**
 ["Что–то" or "что–нибудь"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/6933/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE-or-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C)

[What's the difference between the two suffixes -то and -нибудь?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/whats-the-difference-between-the-two-suffixes-%D1%82%D0%BE-and-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C)

Comment: Russian explanation: http://qaru.site/questions/330836/what-are-free-and-bound-variables

Comment: I'm afraid this is too vague a question for this stack

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, I won't consider the terms you suggested, but perhaps you can find some connection. 
Unfortunately, there are more variants что‐то, кое-что, что‐нибудь, что‐либо, which are hard to explain to foreigners.

1. Что‐то shows that the subject is unknown to both the speaker and the recipient.

> Что‐то промелькнуло в воздухе.

2. Кое‐что means that the subject is partly known th the speaker and unknown to the recipient.

> Я кое‐что помню об этом случае.

3. Что‐нибудь means "no matter what/ not important what "

> Дай мне что‐нибудь поесть.

4. Что‐либо is very close to что‐нибудь, it has a more general meaning of "one of any taken subjects ".

> попросить кого-нибудь (ask somebody, no matter whom ), попросить кого-либо (ask somebody, any unknown  person ). The difference is subtle.

Back to your question: **-то** means "something unknown",  whereas **-нибудь** means "no matter what"

Answer (score 0):

"Что-то" is "something (as in unspecified)", "что-нибудь" ("что-либо") is "anything".

The "free" variables have their (approximate?) equivalent in "независимые переменные".